# What is the word for "idiosyncrasies of a specific group"?

Tags: word-choice

The word *idios* comes from Greek, meaning *one's own*.

Can I use "idiosyncrasies of [group]", despite the subject being a group rather than an individual?

Comment: The etymology of a word does not necessarily tell us _anything_ about its current meaning. See [Etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any reason not to say that a group has idiosyncrasies as you would for an individual. You would, of course, run the risk of making a broad generalisation that is unlikely to apply to every individual in the group.

If you're looking for a single word to describe the shared idiosyncrasies or characteristics of a group, then perhaps [subculture](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subculture) is appropriate.

Comment: You started well, but then mooted the point: you can talk about idiosyncrasies of group, subculture, country, the Earth and also about idiosyncrasies of lines (class), a line (some instance) or the line (a particular instance).

Answer (score 3):

One of the [definitions of idiosyncrasy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiosyncrasy):

> A structural or behavioral characteristic peculiar to an individual or group.